# Spring Controller replacing + character in parameter with whitespace

Tags: java, spring, controller, base64, encode

I have a controller that takes 2 parameters -

```
@PostMapping(value = "/myEndPoint")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> process(final InputStream data,
                                                               @RequestParam final String param1,
                                                               @RequestParam final String base64Param)  {
    return ok().body(doSomething(base64Param.getBytes(), param1, data));
}
```

The base64Param String parameter will contain `+` characters, but of course the Spring controller replaces these with spaces.

Do you know how I can get around this and tell the controller to leave the `+` characters alone?

UPDATE -
I tried

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = fromUriString(format("http://localhost:%s/%s", serverPort, "/myEndPoint"))
            .queryParam("param1", param1)
            .queryParam("base64Param", Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(base64ParamValueWithPluses.getBytes()));
```

but I'm having to decode the base64Param parameter in my controller like this -

```
String decodedBaseParam64 = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodeBaseParam64);
```

Is there a way to encode this so Spring will decode it automatically with the `+` characters preserved?

Comment: That's because `+` is a special character in a URL encoding. Try to send it to your web server as `%2B`.

Comment: I tried that, the `%2B` solution doesn't work as the controller replaces it as a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URI uri = fromUriString(format("http://localhost:%s/%s", serverPort, "/myEndPoint"))
            .queryParam("param1", param1)
            .queryParam("base64Param", "{base64Param}")
            .build(base64Param);
```

source - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21577